# What does the "bagel" setting on toasters do?

Tags: equipment, toasting, bagels, toaster

Usually, I put slices of bread in my toaster.  Sometimes, I toast bagels.  On my toaster, there's a little button that says "bagel".  **How does this setting toast the bagel differently?**

Comment: The question we've always wanted to know but have been afraid to ask.

Comment: Cross-cultural comment: perhaps in more British-influenced parts of the world, the equivalent is known as the "crumpet" setting, and achieves similar results.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill - Speaking as a British toaster-owner, I've had toasters with bagel settings, but never one with a crumpet setting.

Comment: @Jules Thanks, revise that claim to just "in New Zealand" to be more precise.

Comment: I think that prevents the toaster from throwing an exception when it reaches the hole.  It's necessary since tney started programming embedded devices in Java.  (For those not in on the joke, a *toaster* is slang for an embedded device that doesn't have any I/O (the toast doesn’t count).)

Comment: Some things man was just not meant to know.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Unfortunately, the function depends on the manufacturer.

While turning off a set of elements may be common, another option is that the setting may just increase the cook time.  Bagels are thicker and have more mass than sliced bread, so a longer toast time is necessary to have a similar level of toasting.

In particular there are Cuisinart toasters where the bagel button only lengthens the time of the toasting and does not change the pattern.

From [Cuisinart PDF manual](https://www.cuisinart.com/share/pdf/manuals/cpt-122.pdf)

> Bagel button
>
> The bagel feature adds extra time to the toasting cycle
>   to allow for thicker breads. You may also use the bagel button for
>   English muffins and other thick breads.

Answer (score 31):

The bagel setting deactivates or lowers the power on the outer heating elements. This has the effect of toasting the cut surface of the bagel while only warming the outer surface. Generally it's the inner elements that get up to toasting temperature.

Comment: Ok, now why wouldn't I want to toast the bagel's outer surface?

Comment: I guess the fatter profile of the average bagel means that it closer to the heating element, so you risk burning it.

Comment: It depends on the toaster if its inner or outer; there will be a picture of a bagel in the way to insert it.

Comment: @JesseTG : the smooth texture of the outside of the bagel makes it so you're really likely to burn your fingers if you touch it after heating it up.

Comment: @JesseTG Also, because of the way bagels are made (boiled and then baked) the outside crust can be kind of thick. Many people wan't to warm the outer crust without really cooking it further and the "bagel" setting can help with that.

Comment: @Batman Huh. I don't think I've ever actually seen a picture of a bagel on "bagel mode" toasters.

Comment: @KyleStrand On my parents' there's just a "D" (and inverted "D" for the other side) shape; it's not clear it's representing a bagel unless you know. [See this image for an example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Black-Decker-4-Slice-Extra-Wide-Slots-Metal-Toaster-Bagels-Bread-Kitchen-New-/151989536457?hash=item23634846c9:g:B0UAAOSwPc9WyAzA&_trksid=p2349526.m3874.l7936)

Comment: @Random832 I don't think the ones I've seen even have that.

Comment: On my toaster, not using the Bagel button results in the outside starting to singe before the inside gets toasted much. I tried and failed to find my toaster manual. I then read that generally a Bagel button toasts the inside only. So I tried facing the insides in, since that seemed logical and I had a source saying so. It's the opposite. I now have a singed-outside, cool-inside bagel I'm waiting to cool down before trying it inside-out. My toaster is a "Perfect Toaster" model.

Comment: You don't want to toast the outside of the bagel because sometimes there are seeds, raisins, etc., that coat the outside. They may burn.

Answer (score 9):

I have a Dualit toaster and the 'bagel' setting switches off elements on specific sides of each slot, allowing you to toast only the cut side of a bagel or English muffin, which is the norm. If you wish to toast both sides, just use the normal setting.

Comment: Does your toaster indicate which side will get toasted? Mine (different brand) doesn't.

Comment: @Dronz - yes - it's indicated on the body of the toaster.

Answer (score 2):

The bagel setting toasts on one side only. Usually the inside coils so the cut side of the bagel gets toasted while the outside stays soft and warm.